# How to extract names from HTML when user enters @

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this HTML structure:

```
<table id="table-15244" cellspacing="0" class="comment"><tbody>
    <tr id="comment-37">
        <td style="color: #999" class="NV">
        </td>
        <td class="hidden-mob">
            <a><i class="fa fa-caret-up c-voteup"></i></a><br>
            <a><i class="fa fa-bug c-bug"></i></a>
        </td>
        <td class="CT">This is first comment
            <samp>ــ</samp>
            <span>
                <a>Jack</a>                                      // Here
            </span>
            <span class="date_time">
                <span></span>
            </span>
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr id="comment-37">
        <td style="color: #999" class="NV">
        </td>
        <td class="hidden-mob">
            <a><i class="fa fa-caret-up c-voteup"></i></a><br>
            <a><i class="fa fa-bug c-bug"></i></a>
        </td>
        <td class="CT">This is second comment
            <samp>ــ</samp>
            <span>
                <a>Peter</a>                                      // Here
            </span>
            <span class="date_time">
                <span></span>
            </span>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody></table>
```

As I have indicated in the above code (by `// Here`), there is two names that I need to extract them from the HTML. And show them after entering `@` and identical first character with them (in this case `J`, `P`) as a pop-up, And I hide them when the phrase entered in the textarea isn't match with those names. Exactly something like stackoverflow's comments textarea.

How can I do that?

**HTML:**

```
// the above HTML is here
<textarea class="comment" rows="4" cols="50"></textarea>
```

**JS:**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

$(".comment").on('keydown', function(e){
    if (e.which == 50) {  // @ pressed

        /* wait for first character that will be entered
         * if it is match with one or more of those names in the html
         * then show that name as a pop-up on the top of textarea
        */
    }
});
```

Comment: how about this library: `twitter-typeahead`?

Comment: give `<a>Peter</a> ` an id in your HTML (`<a id="myID">Peter</a>`) and get its value in JS by `$("#myID).text()` ?

Comment: your html code base is painful to watch, i can suggest you to drop all and work on solution with jquery's Autocomplete

Answer (score 0):

Add a class to both elements that contain names(or any other element with a name) eg Peter

and use jquery to fetch all of the names in your javascript.

```
 el_names = $('.name');
 names = [];
 for (var i = 0; i < el_names.length;i++){t.push(el_names[i].text)}
```

you then have an array of names you can use in your keydown handler

Also for showing the matched names when you are typing you can use a library like this https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/ (or any others you find better on the net)